# Searching for single Layer in Layers Panel of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, find

I'm working on a project that requires a lot of layers.

Because of this, even if i make different folders, it's sometimes hard to find the layers I want.

Is there a way to simply write a keyword somewhere to find (or highlight) the layer I want in the layers panel?

Is there a plugin for this?

For Example: I want to find the layer "Layer-Orange".

Where can I write "Orange" to find the specific layer?

Answer (score 9):

With a bit of Python, you could search your layer by name, set it as the active layer and make it visible. You can enter the following in the **Python Console** (from the menubar: `Plugins > Python Console` or press *Ctrl + Alt + P*):

```
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer-Orange')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(layer) 
iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```

---

If you want to use *keywords*, you can loop through all layers in the list and find the layers which contains the keyword in the layer name:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if 'Orange' in layer.name():
        iface.setActiveLayer(layer) 
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [loop idea by @Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218289/115) is good.

I just change the `find_layer`of your code to a simple `layer`

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if 'Orange' in layer.name():
        iface.setActiveLayer(layer) 
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For QGIS 3.>

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if 'Municipal_Boundaries_of_NJ' in layer.name():
        iface.setActiveLayer(layer) 
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```